# In Angular-CLI, when does handlebars run and when does HTML template interpolation happen?

Tags: angular-cli

I'm a beginner at all of this (Angular-2, Angular-CLI, Handlebars, Web 2.0 development). I'm just getting started with Angular-2/CLI, and I've noticed something confusing. In the Angular-CLI-generated project, in `index.html`, I see this:

```
{{#each scripts.polyfills}}
<script src="{{.}}"></script>
{{/each}}
```

which, I guess, is processed by Handlebars, somehow?

So, what happens with Angular-2's interpolation, which also uses `{{...}}`?

Do I have to escape the curlies, somehow, or does Handlebars only process certain files, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: You can just ignore that syntax, there's no need to escape anything.

Explanation:
When you run `ng build` (or similar), your `index.html` is parsed and the resulting file is saved in `/dist`.
This file is then served to the browser and won't contain the `{{...}}` parts.
So there is no conflict at all with Angular's interpolation and you don't need to escape anything.

The CLI indeed uses Handlebars internally but the only parsed file is `index.html` [as you can see in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/dcaf9ee6369be45f82a36c982147863e19a866ff/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js#L303).

Also note that in an upcoming release of angular-cli which uses webpack, this syntax disappears completely. (You can already [use the master branch](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#working-with-master) to try it out now)

And just for reference, this was also discussed on Github:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/993